# Existence of the Eigenvalues of an Idempotent Mapping

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a real vector space. If $T: V \rightarrow V$ is an idempotent linear map, and if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $T$, then it may be proven of $\lambda$, that it is either $0$ or $1$. If $V$ were a complex vector space, one need only evoke the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra to conclude of the existence of this $\lambda$. Yet, if $V$ is real, how may we be certain such a $\lambda$ exists?

Comment: Pick a complex eigenvalue (it exists as you said by the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra), then because $T$ is idempotent, this eigenvalue is $0$ or $1$, so it is real ;)

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $V$ is a vector space over any field $\mathbb{F}$. Suppose that $E:V\to V$ is an idempotent linear map, that is $E^2=E$. Then $V=\ker E \oplus \ker (I-E)$, the direct sum of what is clearly the $0$-eigenspace with the $1$-eigenspace.

[The decomposition is trivial to prove: for $v\in V$ we have $v=(I-E)v +Ev$, and $E(I-E)v=(I-E)Ev=0$; and if $v\in\ker E \cap \ker (I-E)$ then $Ev=0, (I-E)v=0$ so add and get $v=Iv=0$.]

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for space decomposition. Let $v\neq0$ be an eigenvector of $E$ for eignevalue $\lambda$, namely
$$ Ev=\lambda v. $$
So
$$ E^2v=\lambda Ev=\lambda^2v. $$
Since $E^2=E$, one has
$$ \lambda v=\lambda^2v $$
which gives $\lambda=\lambda^2$. So $\lambda=0$ or $1$, namely $E$ only has eigenvalues $0$ and $1$.

Comment: This assumes the existence of eigenvalues, the decomposition proves that they exist.